# Redefining \pause to do nothing

Tags: beamer, pause, renewcommand

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand\pause{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
a
\pause
b
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Expected output: a single page with "a b" in it. Actual result: `LaTeX Error: Command \pause undefined.` Why, and how to accomplish the expected result?

Comment: Is there something stopping you from globally commenting out all instances of `\pause`?

Comment: Probably some conflict. Try `\zzpause` or something unique. (generally speaking, redefining built-in things in LaTeX won't end well...)

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\let\pause\empty}` does the trick, while interestingly, `\let\pause\empty` in the preamble does not.

Comment: @Mico No, but it would be neater if could just have a single line controlling this.

Comment: @Carlaonlyprovestrivialprop As `\pause` is a core part of `beamer`, I am wondering what the wider context is here

Comment: @JosephWright For a presentation i like to have the `\pause` as it allows the audience to focus on one thing at the time, and gives empty space to write on. However for later reference i find it annoying to have to press pagedown multiple times; this is also useful when writting the text as i only need it if i'm practicing the presentation. Indeed, i could simply comment every `\pause` each time i want this, but i thought would be cleaner to have a single line controlling this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\pause` command appears to be defined with a delay, i.e., not until the end of the preamble is reached. Hence, what you need is

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\pause{}} % redefine the command to do nothing
```

Incidentally,

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\pause\relax} % "stop whatever you're doing right now"
```

works too.

With either of these adjustments, your code generates "a b" as expected.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\pause{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
a
\pause
b
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```